# Not able to deploy to salesforce sandbox using salesforce DX

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx

I have created a new project with manifest, created new vf page named MyPage, didn't add anything on the page right click on it and selected SFDX:Deploy this source to org and I am getting below error.

> sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath
> c:\Users\myuser\Documents\salesforce
> repository\Prism\force-app\main\default\pages\MyPage.page-meta.xml
> --json --loglevel fatal  ended with exit code 1

There is nothing on my page and error shows nothing but the deployment fails. I can successfully retrieve anything from the sandbox but the same retrieved thing cannot be deployed because it throws the same error.

**UPDATE**

getting below error if I try to deploy from terminal using

sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexPage:MyPage

> MissingMessageError: Missing message
> mdapi_deploy:mdDeployCommandCliCheckOnly for locale en_US. got this
> error if I try to deploy from terminal.

Comment: I would have guessed you weren't authorized (logged in) to the org.  But the fact that you can perform a retrieve suggests otherwise.  Also make sure your page doesn't have a controller missing from the deploy.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Its not about the page I am not able to deploy anything no apex class, LWC etc but I can retrieve everything.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to mismatched API versions, duplicate class names, Authorize an Org, or other issues.  This similar question includes a resolution of running the command in the terminal to get a more verbose error message:
[DeployFailed: Deploy failed. Visual studio code - Deploy to source code failed - SFDX Lightning Component Trailblazer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260008/deployfailed-deploy-failed-visual-studio-code-deploy-to-source-code-failed)

Comment: Thank you for your response, in my case it not about a particular component, I am not able to deploy anything no apex call, vf page aura or lwc but I can retrieve everything.

Comment: Understood.  But you can still get a more expressive error message by deploying via the terminal command.

Comment: MissingMessageError: Missing message mdapi_deploy:mdDeployCommandCliCheckOnly for locale en_US. got this error if I try to deploy from terminal.

Comment: This issue seems to imply that the CLI has a bug and must be uninstalled and reinstalled: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/407  You may also try other google searches for the error, but I'm guessing this is a local config issue and you'll need to reinstall the CLI.  Sorry.